# Pixelated display as if my display was 16bit

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display

I Manually installed the latest Nvidia GeForce GT755m driver.
The installation succeeded without any error but now my display is pixelated as if it was 16 bit.

You can take a look at the picture

http://postimg.org/image/ies1wuf17/

I have asked the same question before but did not get any response (sorry for asking again).
I attempted to solve the problem myself by removing the old Nvidia driver and manually installing the latest version but it did not help.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I solved it by using the opensource driver.
How to mark this question as solved?